# Wheelnav js align Title to the circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wheelnav.js

I am using Wheelnav js and trying to align each title to the inside of the circle (Red region) .But I am missing something, can anyone point out what i maybe missing. 
I need to be able to scroll through the items with mousescrolling but it is not happening either. (on click menu is scrolling is working).

Thanks.

```
var wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
wheel.wheelRadius = wheel.wheelRadius * 2;//2
wheel.navItemsContinuous = true;
wheel.sliceAngle = 8;
wheel.colors = colorpalette.gamebookers;
wheel.slicePathFunction = slicePath().NullSlice;

var anchorAttr = "middle";
wheel.titleFont1 = "200 24px Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif";
wheel.titleFont2 = "200 34px Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif";
wheel.titleAttr = {fill: "#bbb", textAlign: "left", font: wheel.titleFont1,"text-anchor":anchorAttr};
wheel.titleHoverAttr = {font: wheel.titleFont1, cursor: 'pointer',"text-anchor":anchorAttr};
wheel.titleSelectedAttr = { fill: "#000", textAlign: "left", font: wheel.titleFont2,"text-anchor":anchorAttr};

wheel.animatetime = 500;
wheel.animateeffect = 'linear';

wheel.createWheel(["Menu Item -1","Menu - 2","Active Menu Item","Menu - 4","Menu Item - 5","Menu - 6","Active Menu Item","Menu - 8"]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the properties of each navItem after the initWheel function.
The title positioning is possible via slicePathCustomization.

```
wheel.initWheel(["Menu Item -1", "Menu - 2", "Active Menu Item", "Menu - 4", "Menu Item - 5", "Menu - 6", "Active Menu Item", "Menu - 8"]);

//Initial
wheel.sliceInitPathFunction = slicePath().NullSlice;
wheel.navItems[0].sliceInitPathCustom = new slicePathCustomization();
wheel.navItems[0].sliceInitPathCustom.titleRadiusPercent = 0.1;
//Default
wheel.slicePathFunction = slicePath().NullSlice;
wheel.navItems[0].slicePathCustom = new slicePathCustomization();
wheel.navItems[0].slicePathCustom.titleRadiusPercent = 0.2;
//Hover
wheel.sliceHoverPathFunction = slicePath().NullSlice;
wheel.navItems[0].sliceHoverPathCustom = new slicePathCustomization();
wheel.navItems[0].sliceHoverPathCustom.titleRadiusPercent = 0.3;
//Selected
wheel.sliceSelectedPathFunction = slicePath().NullSlice;
wheel.navItems[0].sliceSelectedPathCustom = new slicePathCustomization();
wheel.navItems[0].sliceSelectedPathCustom.titleRadiusPercent = 0.4;

wheel.createWheel();
```

More info about customization [here](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/slicePath.html#customization).